# Command Prompt not accesing desktop

Tags: command-prompt

hello I don't know why my command prompt is not accessing to my Desktop, I run the command "cd Desktop" and
and the response is  "The system cannot find the path specified."

how do I fix this? help

Comment: Try `cd %userprofile%\desktop` instead.

Comment: i tried that same response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop directory is

C:\Users\ "Your  computer name"\Desktop

so if you not at

C:\Users\ "Your  computer name"

then you wouldn't find Desktop. so please refer to http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html
for more detail to navigate around in command prompt